# Why does the circumcentre of a triangle inscribed in a square lie on the diagonal of the square?

Tags: geometry, triangles

There are a few more conditions that I did not mention in the title which can be seen in the sketch below where n is the perpendicular bisector of l, as p is of j. The angle alpha is always 45°.  Why does G lie on the diagonal of the square?

[image: Sketch]

I do not know where to start this proof, the only thing I have discovered that might be useful is that the triangle AGH is similar to ABE and AKG is similar AFD but I do not know how to prove that either.

Comment: Please give all the details, the order of the points / lines in the construction on this page. What is given? How is $G$ constructed?

Comment: The order would be: 1st square, 2nd a random vertex E on the line segment BC, 3rd the line segment AF in a 45° angle to AE, then G as the intercept of the perpendicular bisectors of j and l.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Central angle $\angle EGF=90°$, because it is the double of inscribed angle $\angle EAF$. Hence point  $G$ lies on the circle $c$ having $EF$ as diameter, and at the same time it is equidistant from $E$ and $F$.

But the intersection of $c$ with diagonal $AC$ is equidistant from $E$ and $F$: just consider congruent triangles $EGI$ and $FGH$ in diagram below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The lines to draw in are $EG$ and $EF$. What can we say about the angles in triangle $EFG$ and quadrilateral $ECFG$?

Comment: The base angles in the triangle EFG are equal. They are both 45° but I do not know why. Because they are 45° each, the angle EGF is 90° just as the angle on the opposite side of the quadrilateral, so CFG + GEC = 180°.